# Singular covariance matrix identity

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes

Let $Z=(Z_1,...,Z_n)^T$ be a random vector with mean 0, and define its covariance $\Sigma=\mathbb{E}[ZZ^T]$. Assume that $\Sigma$ is singular. Then I need to show something (non-related to the question), but I was told to start with the identity, that $\alpha^T \Sigma \alpha=0$ (I guess its supposed to be that there exists an $\alpha$ such that it is true), but I fail to understand how that is true, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean to say $\alpha^T \Sigma \alpha=0$

Comment: Correct, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is always positive semi-definite, that is $\alpha^T \Sigma \alpha \geq 0 $ for any $\alpha$.
Singularity occurs when two variables are fully correlated. In other case, a non-zeros $\alpha$ exists such that $\alpha^T \Sigma \alpha=0$. As a small example, assume $n=2$ and $Z_2 = 2 Z_1$, then $$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{1}^2 & \sigma_{1,2} \\ \sigma_{1,2} & \sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $\sigma_1^2 = E(Z_1^2), \sigma_2^2 = E(Z_2^2) = 4\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_{12} = E(Z_1Z_2) = 2\sigma_1^2$, then
$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$
which is singular.

Comment: One quibble with this: The statement about singularity is correct _if_ it is understood that linear combinations of the random variables are also random variables. For instance, suppose $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ have zero mean, unit variance, and pairwise covariance -1/2. Then none of these variables are perfectly correlated with another, but the covariance matrix is singular. The resolution is that $Z_1+Z_2+Z_3=0$ almost surely, so (for instance) $Z_1$ is perfectly anti-correlated with $Z_2+Z_3$.

Comment: yes you can see it that way as well @Semiclassical

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be $\alpha^T \Sigma \alpha = 0$ (the dimensions for forming $Z \alpha$ are wrong). If that's the case then any $\alpha$ in the null-space of the singular matrix $\Sigma$ would do.